# Signals and Interupts When Executing a Program and Killing it

Tags: unix, linux-kernel, signals

I want to understand better the signals and interupts mechanism in UNIX OS. As far as I understand it, interrupts are used to communicate between the CPU and the OS kernel. Signals are used to communicate between the OS kernel and OS processes.

I'm having some hard time understanding what happened on certain scenarios, and finding which signals and interrupts are being called and when.

For example, when executing a program and killing it using `kill pid`. Which interrupts are being triggered when typing the name of the program in the shell (e.g. `pluma` and then `kill pluma_id`)?

I've tried to use `strace` when calling the `kill` command. The first command that is executed is: `execve ("/bin/kill", ["kill", "10057"], [/* 47 cars */]) = 0`

As far as I see, this is a standard syscall, but I cannot understand which interrupts were triggered and which signals were sent when the keyboard key-down-event has happened. I also cannot understand which signals were sent to the process when it was killed using the `kill` syscall (maybe it wasn't sent at all?).

What is the full sequence of events (signals, sisals and interrupts) that happens in the following scenario:

1. Typing `plume` in shell
2. Hitting the enter key and executing `pluma`
3. Executing `kill pluma_id`

(Concise description is more than enough, just to understand the general flow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Typing plume in shell**

Keyboard interrupts occur. The CPU receives the keyboard interrupts, executes the handler, reads the keycode and scan code etc. An event in generated in /dev/input/event* which will be read either by a terminal emulator program or will get forwarded to the program by your input system. Your desktop environment, Xserver etc are involved.

**Hitting the enter key and executing pluma**

Same as above. Upon receiving the enter key, the shell would fork() and exec() pluma.

**Executing kill pluma_id**

Shell process makes the kill() system call. My manual for kill says "The default signal for kill is TERM.  Use -l or -L to list available signals". There will be a context switch when the system call is made. After verifying the permissions, the kernel would find the process table entry for the specified process ID. It will update the signal mask for the process in the PTE with the signal number pluma has received.

Thus the signal is delivered to the process. Now the process needs to handle the signal. If it has installed a signal handler for the particular signal, the handler gets called. Else a default handeler/action will be taken by the kernel. In unix systems, signal handling for a process usually happens during a context switch, ie, when the process switches back to user context or when the process gets scheduled again.

The Design of the UNIX Operating System by Maurice J. Bach has a very simple and detailed explanation of the whole process. You might want to have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Underneath `kill` (the program) used is a `kill()` system call, and this system call always gets a signal number as an argument.

The command `kill` just assumes that certain signals are sent by default, e.g.: `TERM` signal. What you look at `strace` output is program invocation. You should look deeper into the trace, and find where the system call is called. And then you'll see a numerical value of the signal.

You should take a look at the `kill` program documentation I think. It mentions which signal is sent to the process by default, if you don't specify the signal explicitly. It also shows you how to send a specific signal, if you want to.